# Custom UIView not showing anything

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have created a custom `UIView` :

```
import UIKit

class IndicatorView: UIView {

    var image_view_indicator: UIImageView!
    var label_indicator: UILabel!

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)!
    }

    init(frame:CGRect, imageName: String, indicatorValue: String)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.frame = frame
        image_view_indicator = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: 15))
        image_view_indicator.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        self.addSubview(image_view_indicator)
        self.bringSubviewToFront(image_view_indicator)

        label_indicator = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: image_view_indicator.frame.size.width + 3, y: 0, width: 25, height: 15))
        label_indicator.text = indicatorValue
        label_indicator.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.addSubview(label_indicator)
        self.bringSubviewToFront(label_indicator)
    }

}
```

This is my call from `UIViewController` :

```
view_indicator_friends = IndicatorView(frame: view_indicator_friends.frame, imageName: "friend.png", indicatorValue: "20")
```

I cross checked the `IBOutlet` connections. They seem to be fine.
But nothing is showing up in the custom view.

Comment: you are using a Convenience Initializer,but you didn't used the Convenience key word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take your custom view from `Xib` through `IBOutlet` connection then your custom `init` will not invoked that why your `image_view_indicator` and `label_indicator` does not created. Thats why your custom view does not showing up properly. One solution is that implement your code under `init(frame:CGRect, imageName: String, indicatorValue: String)` method in the `awakeFromNib` method.

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
         let frame =  self.frame
        image_view_indicator = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: 15))
        image_view_indicator.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        self.addSubview(image_view_indicator)
        self.bringSubviewToFront(image_view_indicator)

        label_indicator = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: image_view_indicator.frame.size.width + 3, y: 0, width: 25, height: 15))
        label_indicator.text = indicatorValue
        label_indicator.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.addSubview(label_indicator)
        self.bringSubviewToFront(label_indicator)

        }
```

Comment: I don't have xib for custom view. It is only a swift file

Comment: Then you IBOutlet connector connected to which file?

Comment: In the view controller's view, I have added a UIView and set it's class as IndicatorView(custom). And set this view as IBOutlet in viewcontroller

Comment: In this case also "init(frame:CGRect, imageName: String, indicatorValue: String)" method does not call. Implement your initialization under awakeFromNib method.

Comment: How do I pass custom parameters in awakeFromNib ? And still I am not sure that awakeFromNib will work as there is no nib

Comment: @Nitish you can not pass parameter in awake from nib, in awake from nib you just add subview and from your IBOutlet of your `UIView` class from viewcontroller   you can pass image name for that you need to take one property in your `UIView` class

Comment: Thank Mike for the help. If this answer help you then please give upvote Nitish. Thank you

Comment: @Masih : I am guessing removed his answer/comment.